# Alternative method to run the code continuously instead of do-while loops?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a slideshow using a javascript. I have created a loop that is responsible for changing the css of my slideshow. I want this loop to be endless since I want to change the slides after every set interval.

However, the endless loop is causing my whole website to hang and crash. I want to know if there is an alternative approach to this that doesn't cause my whole page to crash?

```
async function startSlideShow(slideshow, leftPos, timer) {

    let slideContainer = slideshow.children[0];

    //How to handle this
    let index = 0;
        do {  
            if (index === (leftPos.length - 1)) {
                index = 0;
            } else {
                changeSlide(index);
                index++;
            } 
        } while (true);

    function changeSlide(index){
        setTimeout(function(){
            slideContainer.style.left = "-" + leftPos[index] + "px";
            console.log("-" + leftPos[index] + "px");
        }, timer * index)
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no need to make an endless loop. Simply Recall the function after interval of time using SetInterval javascript function

Comment: Can you write me a sample code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setInterval, it calls a function continuously by default.  Just put all your counter update stuff inside the interval function.

```js
function startSlideshow(slideshow, leftPos, timer) {
  let slideContainer = slideshow.children[0];
  let index = 0;
  setInterval(
    function () {
      slideContainer.style.left = "-" + leftPos[index] + "px";
      console.log("-" + leftPos[index] + "px");
      index = (index + 1) % leftPos.length;
      // for the range of values index can be, this is equivalent to
      // index = index + 1;
      // if (index == leftPos.length) index = 0;
    }, timer
  );
}
```

`a % b` gives you the remainder when you divide `a` by `b`.  This gives you `a` when `a < b`, and then `0` when `a == b`.  [More info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder)

Comment: That helped me out! However, can you explain how it works -  index = (index + 1) % leftPos.length

Answer (score 1):

Read the comments in the code!

```js
/* Don't need to be `async` */
function startSlideShow(slideshow, leftPos, timer) {

    /* Commenting out to get a working example

    let slideContainer = slideshow.children[0];

    */
    
    let index = 0;
    /* You have to start manually, it will call itself later (see bellow) */
    loopThroughSlides();
    
    function loopThroughSlides() {
        if (index === (leftPos.length - 1)) {
            /* You should call `changeSlide` here as well */
            changeSlide(index);
            index = 0;
        } else {
            changeSlide(index);
            index++;
        }
        
        /* Calling itself after timeout, this makes it endless */
        setTimeout(loopThroughSlides, timer /* Don't need to multiply with `index`) */);
    }

    function changeSlide(index){
        /* Keep the original code, but I replace it with another for demonstarting
        
        slideContainer.style.left = "-" + leftPos[index] + "px";
        console.log("-" + leftPos[index] + "px");
        
        */
        /* Demonstration code */
        console.log(leftPos[index]);
    }
}

/* Calling the function */
startSlideShow(null, ['What', 'is', 'leftPos?'], 1000)
```